# Searching for references within project in Eclipse brings .class files instead of .java file

Tags: java, eclipse, .class-file

I'm use eclipse for developing projects. This on is head scratching. When looking for references of say an object withing the same project(using the menu search>> references >>project) eclipse brings the references in the .class file instead of the .java files. If I delete the .class files then it finds the references in the .java files. I would like eclipse to bring the .java files from the beginning as .class files are no use to me.

Is there a setting somewhere that could address this issue?

Comment: ctrl + shift + t should bring up the "open type" dialog where you can type the name of an object and it will open the source file when you select a class.

Comment: @clav could be useful but not what I'm after. It is a real pain if you want to search for references of an object/method, which normally brings a large list(at least 3 or 4 elements), and do some code analysis. It slows me down.

Answer (score 4):

Check your project properties in eclipse.

Right click the prject -> select properties -> Select java build path -> click on the Source tab.

Check that you haven't included your class file location there.

Comment: As I'm using a ant build script the .class files are generated next to the java files. Does that mean Eclipse will first look at the .class files for the references because of that? I can't change the build script as this is the way this company build and deploy projects.